# How to get 2 fields from MySQL many-to-many relationship?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, many-to-many, knex.js

I have such tables in DB:

```
transaction_item
----------------
transaction_id
item_id

transactions
----------------
id
created_at

store_items
----------------
id
price
```

I need to get object `{created_at: price}`. This is 'many to many', so, `transaction_item` is the main table.

P.S. I wrote something like `object` `{created_at: price}` because I use `knex.raw` to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two joins:

```sql
SELECT created_at, price
FROM   transactions t
JOIN   transaction_item ti ON t.id = ti.transaction_id
JOIN   stote_item i ON i.id = ti.item_id
```